# How to replace content from nest object to parent level in JS array?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have question array inside each `subQuestion` object I want to get element of each question array and push it to parent level array that is `subQuestion`. It's not happening with below code anything wrong with below code?

*main.ts*

```
if (_.isArray(_answerOption.subQuestion)) {
    for (let iLoop = 0, ll = _answerOption.subQuestion.length; iLoop < ll; iLoop++) {
        // compeltely replace the subQuestions with the contents on the question
        if (_answerOption.subQuestion && _answerOption.subQuestion[iLoop].question) {
            _answerOption.subQuestion = _.cloneDeep(_answerOption.subQuestion[iLoop].question);
        }
    }
}
```

*data*

```
{
    "nonClinicalIndicator": "Y",
    "questionId": 2558,
    "questionId2": 116523,
    "questionText": "How much of your medication(s) do you have left? For insurance purposes you must provide exact number of pills, injections, doses etc",
    "answerId": 0,
    "answerType": "SINGLE_SELECT",
    "responseFieldIdentifier": "DOSE LEFT IND",
    "answerOption": [
        {
            "answerOptionId": 2559,
            "answerOptionId2": 116524,
            "answerText": "Yes",
            "subQuestion": [
                {
                    "question": [
                        {
                            "nonClinicalIndicator": "Y",
                            "questionId": 2560,
                            "questionId2": 116525,
                            "questionText": "Number of doses left",
                            "answerId": 0,
                            "answerType": "TEXT",
                            "responseFieldIdentifier": "DOSE LEFT"
                        },
                        {
                            "nonClinicalIndicator": "Y",
                            "questionId": 2561,
                            "questionId2": 116526,
                            "questionText": "When will you take your next dose?",
                            "answerId": 0,
                            "answerType": "TEXT_DATE",
                            "responseFieldIdentifier": "NEXT DOSE"
                        }
                    ],
                    "rxNumber": "15127724",
                    "drugName": "TIKOSYN 250MCG CAPS",
                    "drugNdc": "00069581060"
                },
                {
                    "question": [
                        {
                            "nonClinicalIndicator": "Y",
                            "questionId": 2560,
                            "questionId2": 116525,
                            "questionText": "Number of doses left",
                            "answerId": 0,
                            "answerType": "TEXT",
                            "responseFieldIdentifier": "DOSE LEFT"
                        },
                        {
                            "nonClinicalIndicator": "Y",
                            "questionId": 2561,
                            "questionId2": 116526,
                            "questionText": "When will you take your next dose?",
                            "answerId": 0,
                            "answerType": "TEXT_DATE",
                            "responseFieldIdentifier": "NEXT DOSE"
                        }
                    ],
                    "rxNumber": "15127730",
                    "drugName": "TACROLIMUS 1MG CAPS",
                    "drugNdc": "55111052601"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "answerOptionId": 2562,
            "answerOptionId2": 116527,
            "answerText": "No"
        }
    ]
}
```

*Expected Output*

```
{
    "nonClinicalIndicator": "Y",
    "questionId": 2558,
    "questionId2": 116523,
    "questionText": "How much of your medication(s) do you have left? For insurance purposes you must provide exact number of pills, injections, doses etc",
    "answerId": 0,
    "answerType": "SINGLE_SELECT",
    "responseFieldIdentifier": "DOSE LEFT IND",
    "answerOption": [
        {
            "answerOptionId": 2559,
            "answerOptionId2": 116524,
            "answerText": "Yes",
            "subQuestion": [
                {
                    "nonClinicalIndicator": "Y",
                    "questionId": 2560,
                    "questionId2": 116525,
                    "questionText": "Number of doses left",
                    "answerId": 0,
                    "answerType": "TEXT",
                    "responseFieldIdentifier": "DOSE LEFT",
                    "answerOption": [
                        {
                            "answerOptionId": 0,
                            "answerText": "DRUG 1one dose",
                            "answerOptionId2": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "nonClinicalIndicator": "Y",
                    "questionId": 2561,
                    "questionId2": 116526,
                    "questionText": "When will you take your next dose?",
                    "answerId": 0,
                    "answerType": "TEXT_DATE",
                    "responseFieldIdentifier": "NEXT DOSE",
                    "answerOption": [
                        {
                            "answerOptionId": 0,
                            "answerText": "2019-03-28",
                            "answerOptionId2": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "nonClinicalIndicator": "Y",
                    "questionId": 2560,
                    "questionId2": 116525,
                    "questionText": "Number of doses left",
                    "answerId": 0,
                    "answerType": "TEXT",
                    "responseFieldIdentifier": "DOSE LEFT",
                    "answerOption": [
                        {
                            "answerOptionId": 0,
                            "answerText": "DRUG 2 one dose",
                            "answerOptionId2": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "nonClinicalIndicator": "Y",
                    "questionId": 2561,
                    "questionId2": 116526,
                    "questionText": "When will you take your next dose?",
                    "answerId": 0,
                    "answerType": "TEXT_DATE",
                    "responseFieldIdentifier": "NEXT DOSE",
                    "answerOption": [
                        {
                            "answerOptionId": 0,
                            "answerText": "2019-03-31",
                            "answerOptionId2": 0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "answerOptionId": 2562,
            "answerOptionId2": 116527,
            "answerText": "No"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your example is hard to read, please provide minimum verifable question https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

**You can try like this:**

```js
const data = {
    "nonClinicalIndicator": "Y",
    "questionId": 2558,
    "questionId2": 116523,
    "questionText": "How much of your medication(s) do you have left? For insurance purposes you must provide exact number of pills, injections, doses etc",
    "answerId": 0,
    "answerType": "SINGLE_SELECT",
    "responseFieldIdentifier": "DOSE LEFT IND",
    "answerOption": [
        {
            "answerOptionId": 2559,
            "answerOptionId2": 116524,
            "answerText": "Yes",
            "subQuestion": [
                {
                    "question": [
                        {
                            "nonClinicalIndicator": "Y",
                            "questionId": 2560,
                            "questionId2": 116525,
                            "questionText": "Number of doses left",
                            "answerId": 0,
                            "answerType": "TEXT",
                            "responseFieldIdentifier": "DOSE LEFT"
                        },
                        {
                            "nonClinicalIndicator": "Y",
                            "questionId": 2561,
                            "questionId2": 116526,
                            "questionText": "When will you take your next dose?",
                            "answerId": 0,
                            "answerType": "TEXT_DATE",
                            "responseFieldIdentifier": "NEXT DOSE"
                        }
                    ],
                    "rxNumber": "15127724",
                    "drugName": "TIKOSYN 250MCG CAPS",
                    "drugNdc": "00069581060"
                },
                {
                    "question": [
                        {
                            "nonClinicalIndicator": "Y",
                            "questionId": 2560,
                            "questionId2": 116525,
                            "questionText": "Number of doses left",
                            "answerId": 0,
                            "answerType": "TEXT",
                            "responseFieldIdentifier": "DOSE LEFT"
                        },
                        {
                            "nonClinicalIndicator": "Y",
                            "questionId": 2561,
                            "questionId2": 116526,
                            "questionText": "When will you take your next dose?",
                            "answerId": 0,
                            "answerType": "TEXT_DATE",
                            "responseFieldIdentifier": "NEXT DOSE"
                        }
                    ],
                    "rxNumber": "15127730",
                    "drugName": "TACROLIMUS 1MG CAPS",
                    "drugNdc": "55111052601"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "answerOptionId": 2562,
            "answerOptionId2": 116527,
            "answerText": "No"
        }
    ]
};

// Destructure answerOption property first as we gonna focus on it
const { answerOption, ...rest} = data;

const newAnswerOptions = [];

for (let i = 0; i < answerOption.length; i++) {

 // If the answerOption property has a key subQuestion which is not undefined
 if (answerOption[i].subQuestion) {
  const { subQuestion, ...restAnswers } = answerOption[i];
  let questions = subQuestion.map(x => x.question).flat();
  newAnswerOptions.push(Object.assign({}, restAnswers, { subQuestion: questions }));
 }
 
 // Else simply push it
 else {
  newAnswerOptions.push(answerOption[i]);
 }
}

const res = { ...rest, answerOption: newAnswerOptions };

console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 4));
```